# How can I pipe commands to a netcat that will stay alive?

Tags: netcat

```
echo command | netcat host port
```

This results in the command being sent to the remote host and some data being read back.  But after a few seconds, the connection closes.  The -w parameter did not change anything.  I am using netcat v1.10 on SuSE 10.1.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the remote host that closes the connection?

Comment: Yes.  Doing netcat and then manually typing the command results in netcat staying alive indefinitely.

Comment: Why would it stay alive? it just print the echo parameters and then die?

Comment: I want it to stay alive so that it continues to receive the data coming from the remote server.

Comment: If you do it the way you wrote it, you just send to the remote server. If you want to receive something, you need to open a listening netcat on the local.

Comment: That's not true.  "netcat <host> <port>" opens a bidirectional TCP socket.

Answer (score 42):

This works with the `nc` command on OS X (assuming the command that you want to send is in a file):

```
cat file - | nc host port
```

(Essentially, `cat` dumps the contents of file on stdout and then waits for you on stdin).

By extension, if you want to send the command from the shell itself, you could do this:

```
cat <(echo command) - | nc host port
```

Comment: It's nice as it works on a very bare bones embedded system, where netcat lacks about all the fancy options.

Comment: ``{ echo command; cat;}`` would do the same, and might be considered to be easier to understand.

Comment: As I see it the `netcat` command will hold the socket open until it sees end of input.  All these examples demonstrate this without actually saying much about _why_.  I am interacting with [`SocketTest`](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/) _server_ using `netcat` for an extended period just using: `cat -  |  nc   localhost  8063`.  **[SocketTest](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/)**  is a handy tool that can listen or serve on any TCP or UDP port.

Comment: `cat <(echo command) <(sleep 1) | nc host port` causes stdin to stay open as long as the sleep command runs without the need to set nc timeouts or have the user enter additional characters.

Answer (score 17):

With `nc` on Ubuntu:

```
nc -q -1 host port
```

From the [Ubuntu `nc` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html):

```
 -q seconds
         after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.
```

Note that the available `nc` options vary a lot between distributions, so this might not work on yours (OpenSUSE).

Answer (score 13):

I found it:

```
echo command | netcat host port -
```

My coworker knew it.  I don't see that in the documentation at all.

Answer (score 5):

Might it be that the connection is closed at the other end of the socket?

By default, `nc` closes the connection after completion, if you don't explicitly tell him to stay listening (with the `-k` option):

```
 -k    Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current
       connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option without the
       -l option.
```

See `man nc.1`.

---

I am successfully streaming data between two machines like this:

- sender:

  ```
  while (true); do 
    echo -n "$RANDOM " | nc <host> <port>
  done
  ```
- receiver:

  ```
  nc -kl <port>
  ```

Comment: Can the person who downvoted the answer please specify his/her reason? It is a minimum act of courtesy, and also I might enhance the answer if something is wrong or missing. cheerss

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to manage this with either netcat or socat.  I have just done extensive tinkering with both, and socat looked the most promising.

I managed to set socat up to connect to the remote TCP port and listen on a local unix domain socket (in theory so the link could be kept up all the time) but as soon as the local process detatched from the unix socket (another socat linking the unix socket to stdin/out) it closed the TCP socat session.

The problem here is that each connection through netcat / socat makes a new TCP stream connection to the server, and it closes that TCP stream session when the local end disconnects.

I think you're probably going to have to write some custom proxy software for this that opens the TCP connection to the remote end and then listens locally on a socket / pipe / fifo or whatever and then just sends the data down the existing TCP pipe and returns the results.

Comment: Listen to the all-mighty Matt Jenkins :D

Answer (score 2):

Georges' method works well from an interactive shell, but won't help with scripting, when you're e.g. calling your script as `nohup ./script &`.

I found replacing stdin with a dummy fifo helps.

```
 mkfifo dummy
 cat command.txt dummy | nc host port
```

Since nothing ever writes to the fifo, after outputting the file, `cat` hangs on it indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

`socat`'s `shut-none` option should help here:

> `Changes the (address dependent) method of shutting down the write part of a connection to not do anything.`

You'll probably also need to override the default timeout period using `-t <timeout>`, otherwise the socket will be closed after 0.5s.  This option overrides the default behaviour, which is:

> `When one of the streams effectively reaches EOF, the closing phase begins. Socat transfers the EOF condition to the other stream, i.e. tries to shutdown only its write stream, giving it a chance to terminate  gracefully.  For  a  defined  time socat continues to transfer data in the other direction, but then closes all remaining channels and terminates.`

So, a command such as:

> `echo 'blah' | socat -t 10 stdio tcp:<addr>:<port>,shut-none`

will keep the socket open for 10s after sending the 'blah'.

Answer (score 0):

Your command terminates, if either the remote host closes the connection (or isn't reachable) or the command before the pipe is terminated (while netcat still sends the rest of its input queue).

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora, at least with Unix sockets,
you can also do `echo 'foo' | nc -U ... --no-shutdown` to keep a half-duplex open and receive write responses back despite sending EOF via the non-interactive stdin pipe.

NOTE: Did not try with other connection types beyond Unix Sockets. It might work as well.
NOTE: This will keep the process open forever AFAICT until you Ctrl-C to interrumpt it.